# Microscopically, how does temperature increases in simple exothermic reactions?

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Let’s say we have a simple exothermic reaction $\ce{A_{(g)} + B_{(g)} -> C_{(g)}}$

Since it’s exothermic, that means that kinetic energy of C is greater than the kinetic energy of the reagents. However, momentum still has to be conserved : $p_C = p_A + p_B$. In the center of mass reference frame, we have $p_A = -p_B$ (before the reaction) and $p_C = 0$ (after the reaction). But we just said that $\frac{p_C^2}{2m_C} > \frac{p_A^2}{2m_A} + \frac{p_B^2}{m_B} > 0$ !

What is the way out of this apparent contradiction ? What actually happens in an exothermic reaction ?

Comment: No contradiction: think of two heavy metal blocks on the ground with some TNT between them. Detonate the TNT. BOOM! The two blocks fly apart in opposite directions: lots of kinetic energy and momenta in opposite directions.

Comment: And for the opposite, synthesis case,  the energy is transferred to other colliding molecules/atoms, or a photon is emitted.  If 2 H atoms meet to form H2 and do not encounter the 3rd party to pass energy of bonding they separate again.

Comment: Similarly, nuclear fusions usually end up emitting small particle ( alpha, p, n, e, neutrino, photon ), carrying extra energy and momentum.

Comment: I did flagged for closing. I want to add two simple remarks useful for future confused users. 1) No, the KE of individual molecules is not T. Concept from statistics do not apply to two colliding particles. 2) Chemical reactions aren't elastic collisions at all.